# Migrating from Exchange 2013 to 2019 causes target database to crash

Tags: exchange-2013, mailbox, exchange-migration, exchange-2019

having trouble with migrating Exchange 2013 mailboxes to Exchange 2019. Whenever a mailbox is in the final steps of the migration it causes an outage of the target mailbox (Mailbox Database 2019). The event log on the 2019 server lights up with errors and warnings accompanying every crash. After each crash, the database will re-mount and the migration will finish successfully. I've done several upgrades to 2019 this year but this is my first 2013 -> 2019. The other migrations (2010 -> 2016 -> 2019) went smoothly.
Here's everything I tried to fix it.

1. Moved mailboxes back to 2013. Did this one at a time and re-mounted the database at each crash
2. These are virtual machines, I removed 2019 from the domain and installed on a fresh server. Same issue.
3. Installed a different CU of 2019 (was installing CU6, went to CU3). Same issue
4. Installed Exchange 2016 on another new virtual. Migrating mailboxes to 2016 works with no errors.
5. Migrated from 2016 to 2019, same issue.
6. Migrated from 2019 to 2016, same issue.
7. Called Microsoft, paid $500 and got no where after a few hours. They helped getting everything back onto 2013 and stable there.
8. Made sure MAPI was enabled
9. Set internal and external URLs for MAPI to their correct value
10. Scoured the event viewer for any obscure reference to the database going down and found nothing outside of the Application log.

Here are the 2 errors that have stuck with me from the beginning. Source: MSExchangeIS Event ID 1002. Searching for this error on the internet gave me close, but not quite exact errors that were supposed to be fixed already in older CUs.

> Unhandled exception (System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object
> must have a value.    at
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource
> resource)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.Protocols.MAPI.MapiMessage.IsStreamSizeInvalid(MapiContext
> context, Int64 size)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.Protocols.MAPI.MapiStream.ValidateStreamSize(MapiContext
> context, Int64 size)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.Protocols.MAPI.MapiStream.Write(MapiContext
> context, Byte[] bytesToWrite, Int32 offset, Int32 length)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.Server.Storage.MapiDisp.RopHandler.WriteStreamExtended(MapiContext
> context, MapiStream stream, ArraySegment`1[] dataChunks, UInt32& outputByteCount, WriteStreamExtendedResultFactory resultFactory)    at Microsoft.Exchange.Server.Storage.MapiDisp.RopHandlerBase.WriteStreamExtended(IServerObject serverObject, ArraySegment`1[] dataChunks,
> WriteStreamExtendedResultFactory resultFactory)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Parser.RopWriteStreamExtended.InternalExecute(IServerObject
> serverObject, IRopHandler ropHandler, ArraySegment`1 outputBuffer)    at Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Parser.InputRop.Execute(IConnectionInformation connection, IRopDriver ropDriver, ServerObjectHandleTable handleTable, ArraySegment`1 outputBuffer)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Parser.RopDriver.ExecuteRops(List`1 inputArraySegmentList, ServerObjectHandleTable serverObjectHandleTable, ArraySegment`1 outputBuffer, Int32
> outputIndex, Int32 maxOutputSize, Boolean isOutputBufferMaxSize,
> Int32& outputSize, AuxiliaryData auxiliaryData, Boolean isFake,
> Byte[]& fakeOut)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Parser.RopDriver.ExecuteOrBackoff(IList`1 inputBufferArray, ArraySegment`1 outputBuffer, Int32& outputSize,
> AuxiliaryData auxiliaryData, Boolean isFake, Byte[]& fakeOut)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.Server.Storage.MapiDisp.MapiRpc.<>c__DisplayClass29_1.b__0(MapiContext
> operationContext, MapiSession& session, Boolean& deregisterSession,
> AuxiliaryData auxiliaryData)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.Server.Storage.MapiDisp.MapiRpc.Execute(IExecutionDiagnostics
> executionDiagnostics, MapiContext outerContext, String functionName,
> Boolean isRpc, IntPtr& contextHandle, Boolean tryLockSession, String
> userDn, IList`1 dataIn, Int32 sizeInMegabytes, ArraySegment`1 auxIn,
> ArraySegment`1 auxOut, Int32& sizeAuxOut, ExecuteDelegate executeDelegate)    at Microsoft.Exchange.Server.Storage.MapiDisp.MapiRpc.DoRpc(IExecutionDiagnostics executionDiagnostics, IntPtr& contextHandle, IList`1
> ropInArraySegments, ArraySegment`1 ropOut, Int32& sizeRopOut, Boolean internalAccessPrivileges, ArraySegment`1 auxIn, ArraySegment`1 auxOut, Int32& sizeAuxOut, Boolean fakeRequest, Byte[]& fakeOut)    at Microsoft.Exchange.Server.Storage.MapiDisp.PoolRpcServer.EcDoRpc(MapiExecutionDiagnostics executionDiagnostics, IntPtr& sessionHandle, UInt32 flags, UInt32 maximumResponseSize, ArraySegment`1 request, ArraySegment`1 auxiliaryIn, IPoolSessionDoRpcCompletion completion)    at Microsoft.Exchange.Server.Storage.MapiDisp.PoolRpcServer.EcPoolSessionDoRpc_Unwrapped(MapiExecutionDiagnostics executionDiagnostics, IntPtr contextHandle, UInt32 sessionHandle, UInt32 flags, UInt32 maximumResponseSize, ArraySegment`1 request,
> ArraySegment`1 auxiliaryIn, IPoolSessionDoRpcCompletion completion)
> at
> Microsoft.Exchange.Server.Storage.MapiDisp.PoolRpcServer.<>c__DisplayClass48_0.b__0()
> at Microsoft.Exchange.Common.IL.ILUtil.DoTryFilterCatch[T](Action
> tryDelegate, GenericFilterDelegate filterDelegate,
> GenericCatchDelegate catchDelegate, T state)).

Source: MSExchangeIS Event ID 1013

> The mailbox with mailbox guid 8f656114-9b45-43ac-8073-8ddd3f7596b8 caused a crash or resource outage
> on database "Mailbox Database 2"
> (da3e70b9-c9b1-4937-9fb1-f18324f85926).
>
> Version: 15.02.0464.005        Description: InvalidOperationException:
> S.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException,MEPMAPI.MapiMessage.IsStreamSizeInvalid,MEPMAPI.MapiStream.ValidateStreamSize,MEPMAPI.MapiStream.Write,MESSMD.RopHandler.WriteStreamExtended,MESSMD.RopHandlerBase.WriteStreamExtended,MERCAP.RopWriteStreamExtende

On the face of it I know what the error means...I don't know where to go to fix it.
If you need more info or event logs I will provide.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you didn't get satisfactory issue resolution from Microsoft, you can ask for your money back. 

1. Do you get the same issue when the servers are moved across the virtual infrastructure? i.e different/same servers.
2. Do you get the same issue happening when you specifically turn-off MAPI in the organization? i.e. move would be done through OA.
3. Install CU6 please fro 2019

I assume you100%  validated all the requirements such as OS and .NET?

Comment: 1. We only have one physical host so I'm unable to move the server to a different server. 2. MAPI was turned off during the initial migration, I had turned it on last week. 3. Yes, I validated the requirements.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?  I have a similar error every time OAB generation happens which also dismounts the database.  I also have 2 premier support cases open with MS.

Answer (score 0):

What's the build number of your Exchange Server 2013? Based on my research, the **MSExchangeIS Event ID 1013** seems be caused by the unsupported `.NET Framework` version, the official documentation related with the 1013 event is for your reference: **[Mailboxes are quarantined and databases fail over unexpectedly in Exchange Server 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/administration/mailboxes-quarantined-databases-fail-over)**, and you could run the following commands to check if the current .NET Framework version of your Exchange 2013 CU is  the **[supported/unsupported version](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/plan-and-deploy/supportability-matrix?view=exchserver-2019#microsoft-net-framework)**(At the same time, you could also check it on your Exchange 2019 Server):

```
$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Server) $RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full") [int]$NetVersionKey= $RegKey.GetValue("Release") if($NetVersionKey -ge 381029) { "4.6 or later" return } switch ($NetVersionKey) { {($_ -ge 378389) -and ($_ -lt 378675)} {"4.5"} {($_ -ge 378675) -and ($_ -lt 379893)} {"4.5.1"} {$_ -ge 379893} {"4.5.2"} default {"Unable to Determine"} }
```

Comment: Build number for 2013 is 15.0.1497.2. I ran through the articles and I did have 4.8 installed on the 2013 server. I uninstalled all relevant updates, rebooted and now it's at 4.5.2. I then tried a migration 2013 -> 2019, still causes database outage. Exchange 2019 has .NET 4.8 which is a supported version for CU3

Comment: Sorry for my delay reply. What's the status(**State**) of the database "**Mailbox Database 2**" if you use eseutil tool to read its header? https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-use-exchange-extensible-storage-engine-utilities-eseutil-tool/ (**Use ESEUTIL to read headers**)

Comment: Check your APPLICATION & SYSTEM event log for errors. It is looking like something at the disk/storage level & you need to fix this before migrating. After fixing the SYSTEM related issues, make a backup of EDB and then create a new EDB file and move all mailboxes to the new EDB. Also refer following links:https://serverfault.com/questions/1038496/migration-of-mailboxes-from-exchange-2013-cu23-to-exchange-2019-cu7-causes-the-t                                               https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/error-solved-the-mailbox-with-mailbox-guid-caused-a-crash-or-resource-outage-on-database/